# Editing cloud-init files

Tags: amazon-ec2, systemd, terraform, cloud-init

I've created a `cloud-init` file using Terraform's `aws_instance.user_data` parameter.

This then is executed on start up, on Centos machines, by the `cloud-init` `systemd` service.

I would like to edit this file for dev/testing purposes on the fly then simply restart the said service.

To this end, where can I find the `cloud-init` file that contains the commands run by the `cloud-init` service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Centos machine, this was found in the file:

```
/var/lib/cloud/instances/<instance-id>/user-data.txt
```

Where `instance-id` is found in the file `/var/lib/cloud/data/instance-id`.